# How to send a POST request to send BLOB data from client java script and receive it via MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My current code:

**Javascript**

```
function pushFunc() {

    mediaRecorder.requestData();
    console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        console.log("data size: ", e.data.size);
        var encodeData = new Blob([e.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
        postBlobData(encodeData);
    }

}


function postBlobData(blob) {

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("blobContent", blob);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/Device/Upload");
    request.send(formData);
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
**File: DeviceController.cs**

[HttpPost]
        public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase blobContent)
        {
            ...
            // return View();
        }
```

The Java script code gets the blob from  Media recorder and tries to post it down to the Controller.

1. Am i grabbing and posting blobs the way i should?
2. Should HttpPostedFileBase be used to receive the post request on the server side?

**Fiddler Screenshot#1**

[image]

**Fiddler Screenshot#2**

[image]

**Fiddler Screenshot#3**

[image]